# Reverse digits of integer

Tags: java

Following is the question 
I want to reverse digits of an integer.

- Example 1: x = 123, return 321
- Example 2: x = -123, return -321

My code works for all cases up to 9 digit number. In case of 10 digit inputs it does not write the reverse. What do i do?

My code is :

```
 int reverse1 (int x){
        int n = x;
        int temp = 0;
        if (n > 0){
           while (n > 0){
              int a = n % 10;
              temp = (temp * 10) + a;
              n = n / 10;
           }
        } else {
           while (n < 0){
              int a = n % 10;
              temp = (temp * 10) + a;
              n = n / 10;
           }
        }
        return temp;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `-123 -> -32`, or `-> -321`?

Comment: Did you continue the test like you started, e.g. `123`, `1234`, ..., `123456789`, `1234567890`? Because the reverse of `1234567890` is not `0987654321`, but `987654321`, since numbers don't show leading zeroes. Or did you try `1234567899`, because the reverse is not `9987654321`, as that would exceed the maximum value supported by `int`. In short, don't tell us "it doesn't work" (or words of similar meaning). Tell us (meaning "Show us") exactly *how* it doesn't work!

Answer (score 3):

A 10 digit number is likely to be higher than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`2147483647`), or its reversed number may be higher than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. You can use `long` instead of `int` to support larger numbers.

Comment: Also see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020379/reverse-integer#comment61592327_37020379) for alternate interpretation of "doesn't work".